# How to generate targetNamespace in a web service with Grails and CXF

Tags: web-services, grails, namespaces, cxf

I'm using Grails (2.1.0) and CXF plugin (0.9.0) to generate a web service endpoint and my wsdl is being generated with the package name as the targetNamespace.

According [this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html#DevelopingaService-CreatingtheSEI) tutorial I should annotate my class with @WebService and use targetNamespace property to make it as my needs but didn't work.

Even with the annotation in the service class (not using interface) my generated wsdl first line is:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="ServiceName" targetNamespace="http://com.packageName/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://com.packageName/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

What should I do for a correct targetNamespace?

Comment: Are you using `expose = ['cxfjax']` in your service?  I don't think it'll work with `expose = ['cxf']`.

Comment: @IanRoberts I was using `expose = ['cxf']`. Changed for `expose = ['cxfjax]'` and the targetNamespace was generated correctly

Comment: Glad it helped.  I've made my comment into an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various `@Web*` annotations are only read if you use

```
static expose = ['cxfjax']
```

in your service.  If you're using `expose = ['cxf']` you'll need to change to `cxfjax`.